# HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FORに時々入る値

Tags: php, aws

AWSロードバランサー経由でのクライアントのipアドレスを下記方法で取得しています。

```
$ips = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'] : false;
if ($ips) {
    $ip = explode(',', $ips)[0];
}
```

この `$ip` は99%以上の確率で正しい値が取得出来ているのですが、1%弱の確率で下記形式が入っていることがあります。

```
xxxxxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 
// xは全て数値、(6桁の数字)半角スペース(ipアドレス)
```

6桁の数字は特に規則性も無いようで、00....から始まるものもあれば、90....の様なものもあります。（しいてあげれば、0.....で始まるものと9.....で始まるものが多い模様）
また、この時のipアドレスは172.31.xxx.xxの様なプライベートアドレスになっています。

これはどのような状況なのか、わかる方がいらっしゃいましたら教えて頂けますでしょうか。
また、この6桁の数字は何ですか？
この時にクライアントのipアドレスは取得出来ますか？
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/49346

Answer (score 1):

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ja_jp/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html
X-Forwarded-Forが既に設定されていた場合、カンマ区切りの前についている値がそれなので、X-Forwarded-Forにxxxxxx xxx.xxx.xxx.xxxが指定されていたということでしょう。
これは信用できないと書かれているので、最後の値を見た方がいいかもしれません。